# Is there any way to have the "window.loaded" event with React? or React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Page still loading when componentDidMount finished with its own work, is there any way to detect when all my components, images & resources are fully loaded every time I navigate to different pages on my app?

As far as I was checking this around the internet, it seems imposible.

1. componentDidMount doesn't work
2. adding an eventListener for "window load" only works once
3. React-router doesn't have any feature that could help with this.

Comment: Can you tell more about your use case? What and how are you rendering?